# Rails group by date with count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, group-by

I have the following data columns in my table (using Postgres):

```
occurred_at, name
2012-01-01, Ryan
2012-01-01, Ryan
2012-01-01, Mark
2012-01-01, Ryan
2012-01-01, Paul
2012-01-01, John
2012-02-01, Ryan
2012-02-01, Mark
2012-02-01, Ryan
2012-02-01, Mark
2012-02-01, Paul
2012-02-01, Kevin
2012-02-01, John
2012-03-01, Ryan
2012-03-01, Gary
2012-03-01, Ryan
2012-03-01, Mark
2012-03-01, Paul
2012-03-01, Kevin
2012-01-01, John
```

What I'm trying to do is Group the names by date and add a count and
output this to a json

```
{ date: 2012-01-01, ryan: 3, mark: 1, paul: 1, john: 1 },
{ date: 2012-02-01, ryan: 2, mark: 2, paul: 1, john: 1, kevin: 1 },
{ date: 2012-03-01, ryan: 2, mark: 1, paul: 1, john: 1, kevin: 1 }
```

I have the following code so far:

```
# user controller
 def index
  @users = User.show_data
  render :json
end


# user model

def self.show_data(start = 14.months.ago)
    total_users = users_by_month(start)
    (start.to_date..Date.today).map do |date|
      {
        occurred_at: date,
        total_users[date].name.to_sym: total_users[count],
      }
    end
  end

  def self.users_by_month(start)
    users = where(occurred_at: start.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now )
    users = users.group("date(occurred_at)")
    users = orders.select("occurred_at, count(name) as user_name")
    users.each_with_object({}) do |user, names|
       names[user.occurred_at.to_date] = user.user_name
    end
  end
```

There are about 2 million rows so it needs to be a scalable option.

Thanks in advance,

Ryan

Comment: It does seem odd you're calling the count `user_name`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need this more scalable, you might want to create a `DATE` type column to be used for the grouping and ensure that there is an index on it.

You would use this column in place of `DATE(occurred_at)` for your calculations.'

Keep in mind that this column should be set to the date equivalent of `occurred_at` in the `before_save` callback handler.

Comment: Hi Tadman, sorry I forgot to mention that I have that as a DATE type column.

Comment: If you have it as a `DATE` column, why not use that in your `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Is it not this line? users = users.group("date(occurred_at)")

Comment: `[1] pry(#<UsersController>)> User.chart_data
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "user.occurred_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT occurred_at, count(name) as user_name FROM "u...
               ^
: SELECT occurred_at, count(name) as user_name FROM "users"` That is the error I'm currently getting

Comment: You need to select the grouping column in your results with Postgres. `group("DATE(occurred_at)")` results in a `GROUP BY DATE(occurred_at)` modifier on the results set. What I'm talking about is having a specific `DATE` type column that would not require conversion. Newer versions of Postgres (9.2+?) can compute counts directly from the index itself making this very scalable. Your approach requires converting `DATETIME` columns to `DATE` for each row, then grouping, which could be considerably slower.